# How to animate game object using entities?

Tags: unity, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I am having issues with some of the DOTS stack in unity (mostly the rendering and animation) and was hoping I could use gameobjects for those parts. Not sure how to use entities inside a regular gameobject though, is it possible to do entity queries inside a gameobject to feed an animation statemachine? Or perhaps modifiying gameobjects inside entity queries and using the results in animation state machine that way? I would like to use animation rigging as well.

Comment: I found a breadcrumb here https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-tech-where-is-the-simple-bridge-between-monobehaviours-and-ecs.823485/ so it might be possible if one just manages to find the right classes and methods.

Comment: Found another thread that looks related https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-work-with-standard-animator-with-entities.1167611/, perhaps if I understand both of them I have a solution.

Comment: I've done this before and didn't encounter any problems while accessing an EntityManager from a MonoBehaviour. Can you tell us what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Basically I had no idea at all how to access them from MonoBehaviour until I found the forum posts above, I wasn't even sure it was possible. I have just banged my head at the wall five hours straight due to tons of errors when trying to use com.unity.animation. (Which I want to avoid now until they make some kind of official release)

Comment: So? Did the above forum posts answer your question? Or is there still something you need us to explain to you? When you found out what you were looking for, then please self-answer your question by posting an own answer.

Comment: I can't do hobby work during my work hours. The wallbanging was yesterday. It was just by lucky chance I found the forum posts during breakfast...

Comment: My first attempt failed, I managed to instantiate a single GameObject using System State Component, but for some reason the Animator isn't updated when I set its values inside a Entities.Foreach coupled to my input component. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working after selecting "Convert And Inject Game Object"
[image]

```
using System;
using Unity.Entities;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Components
{
    [GenerateAuthoringComponent]
    [Serializable]
    public struct InputComponent : IComponentData
    {
        public bool IsJumping;
        public bool IsRunning;
        public bool IsCrouching;
        public Vector2 DeltaLook;
        public Vector2 DeltaMove;
        public double DeltaRotate;
    }
}
```

```
using Assets.Components;
using Unity.Entities;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

namespace Assets.BehaviorSystems
{
    public partial class InputActionsUpdatesInputComponent : SystemBase
    {
        InputActions inputActions;

        protected override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            inputActions = new InputActions();
            inputActions.Enable();
        }

        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
            InputSystem.Update();

            InputComponent input = new InputComponent
            {
                IsJumping = inputActions.MainCharacter.Jump.IsPressed(),
                IsRunning = inputActions.MainCharacter.Run.IsPressed(),
                IsCrouching = inputActions.MainCharacter.Crouch.IsPressed(),
                DeltaLook = inputActions.MainCharacter.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>(),
                DeltaRotate = inputActions.MainCharacter.Rotate.ReadValue<float>(),
                DeltaMove = inputActions.MainCharacter.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>()
            };

            this.Entities
                .WithAll<InputComponent>()
                .ForEach(
                    (ref InputComponent entity) =>
                    {
                        entity.IsJumping = input.IsJumping;
                        entity.IsRunning = input.IsRunning;
                        entity.IsCrouching = input.IsCrouching;
                        entity.DeltaLook = input.DeltaLook;
                        entity.DeltaRotate = input.DeltaRotate;
                        entity.DeltaMove = input.DeltaMove;
                    }
                )
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Assets.Components;
using Unity.Entities;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.BehaviorSystems
{
    public partial class InputComponentUpdatesAnimator : SystemBase
    {
        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
            this.Entities
                .WithAll<Animator, InputComponent>()
                .ForEach(
                    (Animator animator, in InputComponent input) =>
                    {
                        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", input.IsJumping);
                        animator.SetBool("IsRunning", input.IsRunning);
                        animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", input.IsCrouching);
                        animator.SetFloat("DeltaLook.x", input.DeltaLook.x);
                        animator.SetFloat("DeltaLook.y", input.DeltaLook.y);
                        animator.SetFloat("DeltaMove.x", input.DeltaMove.x);
                        animator.SetFloat("DeltaMove.y", input.DeltaMove.y);
                        animator.SetFloat("DeltaRotate", (float)input.DeltaRotate);
                    }
                )
                .WithoutBurst()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```